# Algorithm for preventing burst from a producer

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following :

- One producer that produces random integer (around one every minute). Eg : 154609722148751
- One consumer that consumes theses integers one by one. Consumption is around 3 seconds long.

From time to time the producer get crazy and produces only one 'kind' of figure very quickly and then get back to normal. 
Eg : 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666675444696 in 1 second.

My goal is to have as lower as possible as different kind of figure not consumed. 
Say, in the previous sample
I have :

- a lot of '6' not consumed
- one '7' not consumed
- one '5' not consumed
- three '4' not consumed
- one '9' not consumed

If I use a simple FIFO algorithm I am going to wait a long time before all the '6' being consumed. I would prefer to 'priortize' the other figures and THEN consume the '6'.

Does such an algorithm already exists ? (C# implementation is a plus)

Currently, I was thinking about this algorithm :

- have a queue for each figure (Q0,Q1,Q2 ..., Q9)
- sequentially dequeue one item for each queue :

  ```
  private int _currentQueueId;
  private Queue<T>[] _allQueues;

  public T GetNextItemToConsume<T>()
  {
      //We assume that there is at least one item to consume, and no lock needed
      var found = false;
      while(!found)
      {
      var nextQueue = _allQueues[_currentQueueId++ % 10];
      if(nextQueue.Count > 0)
          return nextQueue.DeQueue();
      }
  }
  ```

Do you have better algorithm than this one ? (or any idea)

NB1 : I don't have the lead on the consumption process (that is to say I can't increase the consumption speed nor the number of consumption thread ..)  (indeed an infinite consumation speed would solve my issue)

NB2 : exact time's figures are not relevant but we can assume that consumption is ten times quicker that production

NB3 : I don't have the lead on the 'crazy' behaviour of the producer and in fact it is a normal (but not so frequent) production behaviour

Comment: It sounds like the data structure you want is a priority queue. A priority queue is essentially as you've sketched it: logically an array of queues, each queue has items of different priorities, and higher priority items get consumed before lower priority items. Your variation on it seems to be a "round robin" priority queue, where all the queues are of equal priority and they take turns.

Comment: @Eric : maybe but a does a priority queue handle priority changes ? Say if i have 12345 in queue and then add a 2, I want the two '2' to move back

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling for some discussion of this problem in the context of scheduling work to threads.

Comment: A priority queue typically does not handle items that change in priority, but you could certainly do so. I think for your example though a round robin algorithm would solve the problem.

Comment: Also I am not really a fan of the use of a priority queue in that case because of the priority change : I would need to recompute priority and sort almost at every item insert.

Comment: @toto, why not just use normal list. Iterate it and pick the item with lowest frequency every time? Taking the oldest one on tie.  I can't imagine the selection process being a limiting factor unless you have millions of items. var nextItem=list.GroupBy(...).MinBy(x => x.Count).First();

Comment: @adrianm : most of the time queue will be 0 to 10 items long and 1000 items long during rush, maybe during rush this can be limiting ?

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete example than my comment above:

```
sealed class Item {
    public Item(int group) {
        ItemGroup = group;
    }

    public int ItemGroup { get; private set; }
}

Item TakeNextItem(IList<Item> items) {
    const int LowerBurstLimit = 1;

    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (items.Count == 0)
        return null;

    var item = items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemGroup)
                    .OrderBy(x => Math.Max(LowerBurstLimit, x.Count()))
                    .First()
                    .First();
    items.Remove(item);

    return item;
}
```

My idea here is to sort the items based on their frequency and then just take from the one with lowest frequency. It is the same idea as your with your multiple queues but it is calculated on the fly.
If there are multiple groups with same frequency it will take the oldest item. (assuming GroupBy and OrderBy are stable. They are in practice but I am not sure it is stated in the documentation)

Increase `LowerBurstLimit` if you want to process the item in chronological order except the ones with more than `LowerBurstLimit` item in the queue.

To measure the time I just created this quick code in LinqPad.
(Eric Lippert: please ignore this part :-))

```
void Main()
{
    var rand = new Random();
    var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
                          .Select(x => { // simulate burst
                              int group = rand.Next(100);
                              return new Item(group < 90 ? 1 : (group % 10));
                          })
                          .ToList();

    var first = TakeNextItem(items); // JIT

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    while (TakeNextItem(items) != null) {
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

When I run this code with a 1000 items it takes around 80ms on my 3 year old laptop. i.e. on average 80µs per "Take".

GroupBy should be O(N*M), OrderBy O(M*LogM) and Remove O(N) (N=average queue length, M=number of groups) so the performance should scale linearly with N. i.e. a 10000 item queue take ~800µs per "Take" (I got ~700µs with 10000 items in the test)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 10 queues as you mentionned and select the one from which to dequeue statistically based on the number of element present in the particular queue. The queue with the highest number of elements is more likely to be selected for dequeue.

For better perf, you need to keep track of the total count of elements across all queues. For each dequeue operation, draw a random int X between 0 and total count-1, this will tell you from which queue to dequeue (loop through the queues a substract the number of elements in the queue from X, until you would go below zero, then pick that queue).

Comment: Oh I realize that you want probably to have the probablity inverted. then just use 1/size for example (this said, you need to handle the empty queues differently).